# How do I wait for child components to be "ready" with React hooks?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-component

So I have a `Page` component that contains several `Column` components, each column contains different user-specific markup.

In the `Page` component I need to do some additional mutations (like the column overflow check, pushing columns content around, etc.). For this reason, I need a way to be notified after all `Column` components have mounted - also including implicit mutations have been made.

My first attempt was `useEffect` hook, however, it does get called before the `Column` component even receives it's `ref`.

```
// AppContext
const [columns, setColumns] = useState([]);

const Page = ({children}) => {
    useEffect({
       // This gets called before columns are available
    }, []);

    return (<div className="page">{children}</div>);
}

const View = () => {
    const {columns} = useContext(AppContext);

    return (
        <Page>
            {columns.map(c => <Column>{c}</Column>)}
        </Page>
    );
}
```

Comment: Try using `useLayoutEffect` instead of `useEffect`.

Comment: Thanks, Dear @RA. to accept my answer. I leave an upvote to your question. I hope it motivates you to keep going on Stack Overflow. also, I upvote your other questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, based on ReactJS [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#uselayouteffect) there is a hook exactly like `useEffect` but it calls its callback after all DOM mutations, that name is **useLayoutEffect**:

> The signature is identical to `useEffect`, but it fires synchronously after all DOM mutations. Use this to read layout from the DOM and synchronously re-render. Updates scheduled inside `useLayoutEffect` will be flushed synchronously before the browser has a chance to paint.

I prefer to use `useEffect` because based on Docs maybe using `useLayoutEffect` caused issues about render-blocking.

For your special case, you can use the **useLayoutEffect**.